# ASP.NET Publish error

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis

I've got a web application running on VS 2010, sql server 2008 and Windows 7

It runs fine inside visual studio and on the asp.net development server.

When I click publish I get an exception thrown.

```
The DataSet in data source 'objdatasource1' does not contain any tables. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current      web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The DataSet in data   source 'objdatasource1' does not contain any tables.

Source Error:
```

Is this a connection string problem? Or something else?

Here's my web.config

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="DBConnectionString"/>
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="data source=cdstem; Initial Catalog=****; Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
<add name="****ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=****;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In the app, I'm using "DBConnectionString" which is just my local machine.

> 3005     An unhandled exception has occurred.     9/16/2011 1:51:41 PM
>   9/16/2011 5:51:41 PM    6609e9834ab3483b8eff8edb3aa5269b    8    1
>   0   /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MagazineFormatUpdater-3-129606690952604169
>   Full    /MagazineFormatUpdater
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MagazineFormatUpdater\     CHED-JE    6368
>   w3wp.exe    IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0    InvalidOperationException
>   The DataSet in data source 'objdatasource1' does not contain any
>   tables. at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FilteredDataSetHelper.GetDataTable(Control
>   owner, Object dataObject) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) at
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> > /MagazineFormatUpdater/default.aspx    ::1    False    IIS
> >     APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0    7    IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0    False    at
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.FilteredDataSetHelper.GetDataTable(Control
> >     owner,    Object dataObject) at
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
> >     arguments) at
> >     System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
> >     arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) at
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() at
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() at
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
> >     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() at
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
> >     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> >     includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I'm taking from that that something is wrong with my IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 account and indeed I was getting a mssql error along with the above on my event viewer.

What I did was follow the directions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483479.aspx
pertaining to creating a grant script for that account and the sql error is gone.  The problem is that the error posted above is still displaying.  Any clue as to why?

I took a look in sql profiler and got the stored proc being executed

```
exec dbo.Starch_Display_Pivot @term=NULL
```

I run that inside SSMS and I get the expected rows but inside the published app, I'm getting no rows.  Any ideas?

Comment: How could anyone possibly know what the problem is? There are no tables. This suggests your query returned no rows? Is this because of the query? The parameters? The database used? The data in the database? How could anyone possibly know those answers?

Comment: Also, there is a remove element in your web config. Should that be there?

Comment: @Charlie, the remove element I got rid of but that doesn't make a difference.  I deployed the app twice and got rid of the first deployment due to it being in the wrong folder

Comment: I see your edit, but it's still no help. There's no general "query returns no rows in ASP.NET" problem for anyone to solve - you need to go find out what's wrong with your query, or why it returns no rows in this circumstance.

Comment: Well in SSMS it returns all rows, and in a published web app it returns 0.  Somehow I've missed a step in deployment, hence my post

Comment: You're using integrated security, are you executing the SQL in SSMS under the same account that the web site is using?

Comment: @David, no.  The website is using an IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 account while I'm using my local windows account to execute

Comment: I found my solution.  The exception of 'does not contain any tables' is slightly misleading.  I copied my web application over and just made an empty web site.  While debugging, I was able to recreate the exception I pointed out above but in the catch block, It stated that the login failed for my defaultappPool user.  I followed the directions [here][1]


  [1]: http://selfelected.blogspot.com/2009/10/login-failed-for-user-iis.html

That solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.  The exception of 'does not contain any tables' is slightly misleading.  I copied my web application over and just made an empty web site.  While debugging, I was able to recreate the exception I pointed out above but in the catch block, It stated that the login failed for my defaultappPool user.  I followed the directions on here http://selfelected.blogspot.com/2009/10/login-failed-for-user-iis.html